# How to sleep 10 seconds before running a linux command?

Tags: linux, cron

Simple question: I want to run a cron operation every minute at the 10th second (for example at 2:00:10 PM). The cron operation runs a curl command to download a website page. How can I run a cron operation to do that?

Current crontab setting:

```
* * * * * curl http://www.google.com/
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
* * * * * sleep 10;curl http://www.google.com/
```

Comment: This is fine, but remember that google.com might take more than 50 seconds to fetch, all cron jobs *ever* should check if a previous instance is still running and prevent multiple instances. Cron itself does not generally do this.