# Offset Crons with Sleep and Flock together

Tags: cron, sleep, flock

I run several cron jobs every minute - I use flock to prevent overlapping as a couple of the scripts may run for over minute:

```
* * * * * flock -n /path/to/lock-process-1.txt php /path/to/process-1.php

* * * * * flock -n /path/to/lock-process-2.txt php /path/to/process-2.php
```

However, all the processes run at the same time (and most of the processes only take a few seconds). So I'd like to stagger the crons so that they are ten seconds apart. I have read elsewhere that this can be done with sleep ([from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420799/how-to-sleep-10-seconds-before-running-a-linux-command)):

```
* * * * * sleep 10;curl http://www.google.com/
```

My question is: can I use sleep alongside flock and if so, where do I add the `sleep 10;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and tested this and it is OK to have sleep before flock:

```
* * * * * sleep 10; flock -n /path/to/lock-process-2.txt php /path/to/process-2.php
```